# can I use shared memory between two applications one in c o r c++ and one in java

Tags: java, c++

I am talking about java c++ and random access memory
Any pointers?

The problem is I think java has it's own memory management, so.any pointers?

Comment: "Any pointers?" No, Java doesn't have pointers.

Comment: Use JNI to map and access the shared memory.

Comment: Yes, you'd need to use JNI.  How difficult it would be I haven't a clue.